# ABC conjecture for multivariate polynomials?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

Is there an ABC conjecture for multivariate polynomials over $R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ where $R$ is either $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb F_q$?

Comment: Are you asking whether there is a common generalization of [Mason's theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.0434) for multivariate polynomials over $\mathbb{C}$ and the $abc$ conjecture over the integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mason-Stothers Theorem also holds for  polynomials over fields of prime characteristic. But one has to modify the assumption, that the polynomials $a(x),b(x),c(x)$ are non-constant by another condition, namely by the stronger assumption $(iii)$:

**Theorem (Mason, Stothers)**:  If $k$ is a field and $a(x)$, $b(x)$, and $c(x)$ are nonzero polynomials in $k[x]$ such that 
(i) $a(x) + b(x) = c(x)$, 
(ii)  $\gcd(a(x),b(x)) = 1$, 
(iii) at least one of the derivatives $a'(x)$, $b'(x)$, or $c'(x)$ is not $0$,

then we have 
$$
\max(\deg a(x), \deg b(x), \deg c(x)) \leq \deg({\rm rad}(a(x)b(x)c(x)) - 1.
$$

The above link in the comments shows that there is also a generalised version for multivariate polynomials.